# The golang regular expression gets the SQL statement in the log file

Tags: sql, regex, go, logging

I tried to get the SQL statement in the log file through the regular expression of golang, but there were some problems with the matching results. If the SQL did not break lines in the code, the correct result could be obtained, but if it was long and divided into multiple lines in the code, my SQL could only be part of the first line。my expectation is to get two full SQL
Below are my code and some sample logs

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    file, err := os.OpenFile("/home/gopath/src/log.txt", os.O_RDWR, 0766)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    res, err := ioutil.ReadAll(file)
    reg := regexp.MustCompile(`\[ORM\].*`)
    str := reg.FindAllStringSubmatch(string(res), -1)
    fmt.Println(str)
}
```

> [ORM]2018/08/03 10:23:50  -[Queries/read] - [  OK /    db.Query /   432.4ms] - [SELECT acc.*,gp.group_name,gp.group_id,org.org_name,group_concat(r.role_name) role_name
>               FROM sys_account acc
>               LEFT JOIN sys_org org on org.org_id=acc.org_id
>               LEFT JOIN sys_group gp on gp.group_id=org.group_id
>               LEFT JOIN sys_account_role ar on ar.acct_id=acc.acct_id and ar.is_del=0
>               LEFT JOIN sys_role r on r.role_id=ar.role_id  where 1=1  and acc.acct_type=1  group by acc.acct_id order by acc.create_time  desc  LIMIT 0, 15]
>   nsq consumer2: INF   13 [RYOLST_Ch_admin/crm] (192.168.1.233:4150) received CLOSE_WAIT from nsqd
>   nsq consumer2: INF   13 [RYOLST_Ch_admin/crm] (192.168.1.233:4150) beginning close
>   nsq consumer2: INF   13 [RYOLST_Ch_admin/crm] (192.168.1.233:4150) readLoop exiting
>   nsq consumer2: INF   13 [RYOLST_Ch_admin/crm] (192.168.1.233:4150) breaking out of writeLoop
>   nsq consumer2: INF   13 [RYOLST_Ch_admin/crm] (192.168.1.233:4150) writeLoop exiting
>   [ORM]2018/08/03 10:23:50  -[Queries/default] - [  OK /    db.Query /     0.6ms] - [select * from sys_group where group_id=? ] - `1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this pattern: `\[ORM\][\w\W]+?\wms\][ -]+\[([\w\W]+?)\]`.

Explanation:

`\[ORM\]` - match `[ORM]`,

`[\w\W]+?\wms` - match any character (inlucding `\n`) until `\wms` is found (`\w` is a word character, can be digit as well) - non greedy, so it stops at first occurence of `\wms`, so it won't capture until the second SQL log.

`([\w\W]+?)\]` - capturing group, that will contain full SQL statement, again non-greedy search for any character, similairly as above.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Py8IHO/5)

Comment: It is effective to try the method you provided, thank you  :P